# nginx proxy_pass regexp to another domain

Tags: nginx, regex

I have photoURL http://cs10821.vk.me/u712377/d_9da50e0f.jpg
It is does not have header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
I fix it with nginx. If I write

```
location /photo/cs10821.vk.me/u712377/d_9da50e0f.jpg {                  
    proxy_pass http://cs10821.vk.me/u712377/d_9da50e0f.jpg;             
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

all work fine. I write http://servername.ru/photo/cs10821.vk.me/u712377/d_9da50e0f.jpg
and I have my photo with header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
But if I use regex

```
location ~ ^/photo/(.*)$ {      
    proxy_pass http://$1;               
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

I have error 502. 
Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the error log. You should have resolver defined.

Such as /etc/nginx/conf.d/resolver.conf:

```
resolver 8.8.8.8;
```

Comment: Excellent. Everything is working. Thank you very much